# Is there a way to tell if a Li-ion battery has been discharged to deep even after they have been charged again?

Tags: lithium-ion

I have a Li-ion battery pack (1s3p) and would like to know if it had been discharged too deep in the past. Is there a way to measure this even though the batteries have been charged again?

Comment: What charging equipment do you have? Does it have any capability to measure charge/discharge? Is it a second-hand item, or do you have some other reason to worry about it?

Comment: What you can measure somewhat easily are charge capacity and ESR. If they are close to rated values from the datasheet then the pack is probably OK. If you don't have a datasheet, and you don't know what the capacity and ESR are supposed to be when the pack is new, then there is very little you can do. So how about if you edit your question to include a link to the datasheet for the pack or cells?

Comment: If a lithium battery cell is discharged too low then The Battery University and many battery charger IC datasheets say that a fragment of solid Lithium is plated and can short the cell and fuse if a normal charge is attempted causing an explosion of Lithium fire. A battery charger IC detects a low voltage then tests for normal charging current. if the current is higher than normal then charging is not done an an error is shown. A cell discharged too low also has reduced capacity.